# "There's no block I put my head on" ("put one's head on the block")

Tags: grammar, idioms, word-usage, phrase-usage

There's an idiom "put one's head on the block" which means "to risk doing something which will make other people lose their good opinion of you if it fails".

So I have a question: If I convince somebody of something (or promise something to someone), can I say after that something like "**There's no block I** (/**to**?) **put my head on**" meaning "there's no any risk of failure for me, I can guarantee I'm telling the truth, you can trust me", etc.?

The reason I'm so interested in that idiom is because I want to use it in my short poem. So I think it's ok if it sounds a bit odd but I still want it to be understandable and grammatically correct.

Thank you.

Comment: 'Trust me, I've no axe to grind.'

Comment: Writing advice and proofreading are out of scope on this site. That being said, I see nothing grammatically wrong with the construction. Poetically speaking, I'd interpret it to mean that you aren't sticking your neck out. In other words, that you are not taking a risk. I wouldn't have imagined that it meant you guarantee you're telling the truth.

Answer (score 4):

Idioms, generally, don't make sense.  We understand them only because we've learned them, basically, through previous exposure.

Because of this, I think it's extremely risky to attempt to adapt them. "There's no block to put my head on" (the better of your two alternatives) doesn't really work, and I'll attempt to explain why.

"Put one's head on the block" is a reference to **execution**, probably by axe but possibly by guillotine.  Ie, shortly after putting your head on the block, unless someone intervenes or you escape by some other miracle, an executioner standing over you will swing his axe down and chop your head off.

If you say "There's no block to put my head on", that conjures up an image of a condemned prisoner **complaining** that the block is missing - like a hotel guest complaining that there's no pillow on his bed.  In other words, you're not saying there's no risk, you're saying that the missing block is going to prevent you from being killed.  However, that still suggests that you are a condemned prisoner, waiting around until someone eventually finds a block, or perhaps the executioner gets impatient and just tells you to put your head on the floor so he can get on with it.

A better way to say this would simply be to say "I'm not putting my head on the block", which just means "There's no great risk for me".  However, this implies that there **is** great risk for someone, just not you.  This isn't reassuring for a client, for example.

If you wanted to say that there's no risk **at all**, it's better to avoid the idiom/metaphor altogether, as the idiom is inescapably linked to the idea of someone taking a massive risk.

Answer (score 1):

The expression [*have/put your head on the block*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-put-your-head-on-the-block) means that ***you***  might run a big risk:
​

> - to risk a bad thing happening to you by doing something or helping someone:
>
>   - *I'm not going to put my head on the block for you.*

what you want to say is that they can trust you, so the expression you may want to use is:

> - You are not running any risk with me

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I exactly meant that **I risk** by making a promise that may be broken. For example if I tell somebody that I can do that job, give it to me, I'll do it perfectly, and then I fail and that person doesn't want to work with me anymore, I can say I was running a risk when I said that I would do that job, right? So, the question is, is it correct to transform "put my head on the block" to "There's no block I put my head on", if I mean that **I'm** not running any risk by saying that, I'm absolutely self-confident, 100% sure? Or what form would be correct...